# Output structure in a <ul>

Tags: structure

Given a structure that has, for example, three levels of content—how do I just iterate over it and create a nested `<ul>` reflecting the hierarchy and containing the `title` and `slug` (as a link) of each entry?

The following just gives me a flat representation of the structure:

```
<div class="panel">
    <h2>People</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for entry in craft.entries.section('people') %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Craft's built-in `{% nav %}` tag would save you having to write your own recursive macro:

Adapted from http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/nav

```
<div class="panel">
    <h2>People</h2>
    <ul>
        {% nav entry in craft.entries.section('people') %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
                {% ifchildren %}
                    <ul>
                        {% children %}
                    </ul>
                {% endifchildren %}
            </li>
        {% endnav %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's not quite as flexible, but is more readable. It should be all you need if it's just links to the entries you want, and it *might* be a tiny bit faster, but I haven't actually compared twig's compiled macro vs it's tag code.

Comment: Amazing, will try this.

Answer (score 6):

This could be achieved through a recursive macro:

```
{% macro recursive_nav(entries, depth) %}
{% import _self as self %}
<ul>
    {% for e in entries %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ e.url }}">{{ e.title }}</a>
            {% if e.hasDescendants() %}
                {{ self.recursive_nav(e.children, depth+1) }}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endmacro %}
```

And then to use it in your template:

```
{% import '_macros/recursive-nav.twig' as rn %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.section('people').level(1) %}
<div class="panel">
    <h2>People</h2>
    {{ rn.recursive_nav(entry, 1) }}
</div>
```

This was borrowed and slightly modified from Marion's answer [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/custom-or-complex-nav-tag/1734#1734). That question is also a great resource for other ways to achieve this result.

Comment: Great answer. I guess this isn't possible without the macro unless you know how many levels deep you'll be going.

Comment: Right because the macro is used for recursion. If you know how many levels you're going you can just keep looping. You could also setup a macro to only loop a finite amount or accept a number of levels as a variable.