# Complex Navigation

Tags: navigation, children

I need to output different HTML for children of navigation. When i use

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages') %}

<ul id="nav">
    {% nav entry in entries %}
        <li class="whatever">
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

It outputs my children having class="whatever" as well. I don't want that, i need something else for the children.

I saw the post here: [Custom or complex nav tag](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/custom-or-complex-nav-tag) about using LEVEL however i don't quite understand how i would write the code for that. Could anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to set a conditional for the entry level for the parent, which is `1`.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages') %}

<ul id="nav">
    {% nav entry in entries %}
        <li{% if entry.level == 1 %} class="whatever"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I ended up outputting it with this, a lot of conditionals (because there was more to be changed than i showed for simplicities sake) but it seems to do the trick so it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

As the children inherit the settings between the {% nav %}...{% endnav %} so to show an active state on a navigation use...

```
<ul>
    {% nav entry in craft.entries.section('entry') %}                               
        <li class="
            {% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == entry.slug or 
                  craft.request.getSegment(2) == entry.slug %}
                selected
            {% endif %}
            {% if craft.entries.section('entry').descendantOf(entry).find() | length > 0 %}
                has-children
            {% endif %}
        ">
            {{ entry.getLink() }}
            {% ifchildren %}
                <ul>
                    {% children %}
                </ul>
            {% endifchildren %}
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Or use entry.level to target the different levels if you need to.