# display entries inside nav

Tags: entries, navigation

I'm building an overview page that will show a title, thumbnail, etc of the pages inside the structure. I want the nav children to start at the parent page we're currently on. I can get the correct elements to display - they just don't have any entry data like title.  If there's a better way to approach this let me know.

```
{% set overview = (entry.level == 1) ? entry : entry.getAncestors().level(1).first() %}

{% nav entry in overview %}

{{ cycle(['<div class="overviewrow">', '', '', ''], loop.index0)|raw }}
    <div class="col">
        <a class="marketlink href="{{ entry.url }}">
        <div class="marketwrap">
            {% for block in entry.contents.type('image').limit(1) %}
            {% if block.image | length %}
            {% for image in block.image.limit(1) %}    
                      <img src="{{ image.getUrl('blogThumb')}}" alt="{{ image.altText }}">   
            {% endfor %} 
            {% else %}
                      <img src="/something.jpg">
            {% endif %} 
          {% endfor %} 
                      <div>{{ entry.title }}</div>
        </div></a></div>
        {% ifchildren %}
                {% children %}
        {% endifchildren %}

  {{ cycle(['', '', '', '</div>'], loop.index0)|raw }}


 {% endnav %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need to use the `nav` tag, you can just spin through the `entries` in a normal `{% for entry in entries %}` loop, making use of the [`level`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#level) property and the [`getDescendants`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getDescendants) method.

There are some good suggestions for more complicated `nav` code in this answer:

[How do you handle complex navigation in Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1847/142)

and there's some good pointers in the answers to this question:

[Custom or complex nav tag](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1733/142)

Comment: I tried following one of the examples but apparently it's no correct. Now it's only returning the parent page name for each child and no other entry data.
    {% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').id('not 1').level(1) %}
          {% for page in pages %}
            {% if page.hasDescendants %}
             <div>{{ entry.title }}</div>
       {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

Comment: @David - Have you tried it without the `.level(1)`? It's my understanding that by adding this, you are saying you only want the top level entries returned, so in effect you are saying don't fetch the children.